# is there any function to generate a UNIQUE string or UNIQUE number?

Tags: asp.net, unique

I need for function to generate a UNIQUE string, like:

> DIM uniStr as string =
>   generateUniStr()

is there any function already do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
Dim uniStr = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

Comment: Remembering that GUIDs are not guaranteed to be unique, but for all practical purposes are.

Answer (score 3):

You can gen up a GUID and stringify it.

You might want to give more details on what you're really looking for, because it's likely there's a better solution.